# ¿Porque el primer carácter que leo de un fichero de texto en lenguaje C siempre es el carácter de nueva linea?

Tags: c, archivo, procesamiento-de-texto

Estoy intentando etiquetar cada titulo de un archivo de texto en lenguaje c, y me imprime las etiquetas en la pantalla y un salto de linea, etiqueta y salto de linea, etiqueta y salto de linea...y creo que el problema es que la variable `c=getc(f)` siempre es igual a un salto de linea--> '\n', porque?//

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("archivo.txt","r+");
    fpos_t pos1, pos2;
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    do
    { 
        /* 
            Lee el primer caracter del archivo que si es distinto de '\n'
            sale del bucle
        */
        do
        {
            c=getc(f);
        }while((c=='\n')&&(!feof(f)));     
        fgetpos(f,&pos1); /* Obtenemos la posición actual en archivo */

        /* 
            Aquí se van leyendo caracteres hasta encontrar '\n' con
            lo que sale del bucle siendo c='\n'  
        */
        do
        {
            c=getc(f);
        }while(((c)!='\n')&& (!feof(f))); 

        /* Aquí retrocede 2 posiciones */
        fseek(f,-2,SEEK_CUR);    
        /* Leemos caracter en la nueva posición actual */
        c=getc(f);
        /* Si dicho caracter es un punto entramos en la condicional */ 
        if((c!='.')&&(!feof(f)))
        {
            ++i;   
            /* Establecemos la posición en &pos1 calculada al leer el 1er caracter */
            fsetpos(f,&pos1);  
            /* Retrocedemos 3 posiciones desde la actual que hemos preestablecido */
            fseek(f,-3,SEEK_CUR);
            /* Se muestra el valor de i */
            printf("Etiqueta Nro %d:\n",i);
        }
        /*
            En este bucle lo último que imprime es '\n' que al haber retrocedido
            la posición en base a '\n' lo que nos encontramos es precisamente '\n'            
        */  
        do
        {                     
            c=getc(f);
            printf("%c",c);
        }while(((c)!='\n')&&(!feof(f)));
    }while(feof(f)==0);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Esste es el contenido del archivo.txt:

¿Para qué sirve la fotosíntesis?|!
Como ya hemos visto, la fotosíntesis sirve, en principio,  para que las plantas se alimenten,  sintetizando materia orgánica a partir de energía luminosa.

Gracias a este proceso, las plantas proveen oxígeno y renuevan el aire, eliminando el dióxido de carbono o CO2.

¿Cómo y dónde se lleva a cabo?
El proceso de fotosíntesis que es cómo obtienen energíavlas plantas se  divide en cuatro etapas principales :

Absorción: Las raíces absorben el agua y los minerales de la tierra.
Circulación: Los nutrientes circulan desde la raíces hasta las hojas a través del tallo.
Fotosíntesis: Se realiza en las hojas, las cuales se orientan hacia la luz para llevarla a cabo. La clorofila contenida en los cloroplastos permiten atrapar la luz (captan la luz solar) que, en combinación con el dióxido de carbono absorbido por los estomas de la planta, ayuda a transformar la savia bruta en savia elaborada.
Alimentación: durante el proceso se produce el oxígeno, el cual es expulsado por las hojas. El oxígeno es equivalente al desecho posterior a la alimentación. Es aquí donde se produce el transporte de la cadena de electrones y la fijación del dióxido de carbono.
Respiración: Este proceso se produce tanto de día como de noche. Durante el día, con la presencia de la luz del sol, las hojas realizan la fotosíntesis y desechan el oxígeno. Por las noches, al no haber luz que puedan absorber, las plantas se limitan a respirar únicamente.
Los factores esenciales  que contribuyen para que se realice la fotosíntesis son varios. Vamos a hacer una explicación detallada de cada uno de ellos.

¿Qué componentes necesita la fotosíntesis para desarrollarse?
A continuación exponemos los elementos que requiere la fotosíntesis para llevarse a cabo de forma correcta:

Intensidad de la luz
Sin luz, las plantas no pueden realizar la fotosíntesis, aún si hay suficiente agua y dióxido de carbono en el ambiente.

Si la luz es escasa, la fotosíntesis se realiza más lentamente.

Concentración de dióxido de carbono
El dióxido de carbono es un reactivo necesario para que el proceso se dé.

El Agua
Durante la fotosíntesis, la planta desdobla las moléculas de agua absorbidas de la tierra, dividiéndolas en hidrógeno y oxígeno. Como resultado de esta reacción, el oxigeno es liberado en el ambiente, mientras que el hidrógeno es aprovechado en otros procesos.

Durante la fotosíntesis, el dióxido de carbono se combina con el hidrógeno liberado, y juntos forman glucosa.

Las reacciones químicas que combinan el dióxido de carbono y el agua para producir glucosa están controladas por enzimas, lo que nos lleva al cuarto factor determinante.

dibujo del proceso de fotosíntesis

La Temperatura
Todas las reacciones controlada por enzimas se ven afectadas por la temperatura.

A bajas temperaturas, la tasa de fotosíntesis está limitada por el número de colisiones moleculares entre enzimas y sustratos.

A altas temperaturas, las enzimas se desnaturalizan, lo que equivale a que su estructura y funciones se ven alteradas.

Cantidad de clorofila
La clorofila es indispensable para absorber la energía lumínica  que se requiere para convertir el dióxido de carbono y el agua en glucosa.
dibujo de la fotosíntesisLas hojas que contienen mayor cantidad de clorofila son más capaces de absorber la luz.

Las plantas en condiciones precarias de iluminación sintetizan más clorofila para absorber la cantidad de luz que requieren.

Algunas enfermedades de las plantas pueden afectar la cantidad de clorofila y, por lo tanto, su capacidad para realizar la fotosíntesis.

Comment: Imposible ayudarte. Ese código está totalmente desordenado, ¡no se entiende nada! Trata de ordenarlo mejor y recibirás ayuda.

Comment: listo, lo arreglé

Comment: El código seguía desordenado. Solo por esta vez lo ordené. Siempre trata de publicar el código ordenado, con su respectiva *sangría*.

Comment: okey, muchas gracias.lo tendré bastante en cuenta

Comment: la primera "c" dentro del do, me sugiere que c es siempre un salto de linea , LN="\n", sabrá alguien porque?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar en que parte del código `c` vale `\n`? Me refiero en cual de los `do-while`, ya que veo varios `c=getc(f);`. También sería útil que digas que datos tienes guardado en el archivo, así puedo probarlo..

Comment: me día cuenta que c vale \n en la linea 14, y los datos que tengo en el archivo, son párrafos de caracteres. archivo.txt es un archivo de tipo texto plano(.txt), con información como la siguiente:

Comment: iba a escribir el tipo de párrafos que tiene el texto, pero veo que no me deja copiar aquí los saltos de linea, entonces puede causar confusión

Comment: Agrega esa información en la pregunta. Dale en la opción de **editar**.

Comment: Podrías explicarte mejor, ya que el código es un poco lioso y no entiendo del todo lo que pretendes. Cuando dices que quieres imprimir las etiquetas a qué te refieres.

Answer (score 1):

después de darle muchas vueltas creo que sé qué es lo que hace tu código y todo es muy resumible y simplificable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   FILE *f;
   f=fopen("archivo.txt","r+");
   char c;
   int i = 0;

   while (!feof(f))
   { 
       i++;
       printf("--------Etiqueta Nro %d:\n", i);
       do
       {
            c=getc(f);
            if (c != '\n')
               printf("%c", c);
       } while( c!='.' && !feof(f) );  
       printf("\n--------------------------\n"
   }
   fclose(f);
   return 0;
 }
```

Como observo que tu código sólo imprime "Etiqueta Nº" cuando encontramos un punto. Entonces el código modificado imprime cada cada frase encontrada en el archivo leyendo carácter a carácter hasta encontrar un '.' y omite los salto de linea en la impresión ya que no son significativos. Eso es si lo que queremos es mostrar las frases. Si quisiéramos mostrar los párrafos entonces cambiaríamos en la condicional c != '.' por c != '\n'.

EXTENDIDO:
Para poder detectar párrafos asegurando que no dependa sólo del salto de línea, sino que además haya un punto y a parte yo lo haría así:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   FILE *f;
   f=fopen("archivo.txt","r+");
   char c;
   char cPrev;
   int i = 0;

   while (!feof(f))
   { 
       i++;
       printf("--------Etiqueta Nro %d:\n", i);
       do
       {
            c=getc(f);
           
            // Si encontramos un punto y aparte
            // salimos del bucle porque es un párrafo.
            if (cPrev == '.' && c == '\n') 
                break;
            else
                printf("%c", c);
         
            // Guardamos el valor actual
            cPrev = c;
       } while( !feof(f) );  
       printf("\n--------------------------\n"
   }
   fclose(f);
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Tu eres el que mas cerca ha estado de entender el programa, al decir que quiero poner etiquetas a algunas partes del programa, quiero decir que le pondré un titulo, que en este caso, quiero que sean de la forma: "Etiqueta Nro N :"  donde N vendría a un numero ascendente contando desde cero.La cuestión es-que no quiero que me omita los saltos de linea(al menos no todos) solo aquellos que vengan a ser el final de algún titulo presente en el texto (frase que no contenga un punto y aparte) para luego poder de esta manera identificar los sitios donde se le escribirán las etiquetas

Comment: Te he extendido la respuesta para el caso de l punto y aparte.